# Failed to create provisioning profile in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I randomly just got this error on a project I've been working on for a while.

> Failed to create provisioning profile. There are no devices registered in your account on the developer website. Select a device run destination to have Xcode register it.

and

> No profiles for 'com.user.App' were found: Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'com.user.App'.

This just randomly happened while I was trying to preview my program, just as I have done many times before.  It says None Required on provisioning profile and I'm trying to select either Sign to Run Locally or Development under signing certificate and I can't pick either option.

When I clean the project all 97 errors go away, but return when I try and preview the project.  I have been previewing in the simulator but now I have no option to do that for some reason.  It just says "My Mac" and "Any Mac" where "iPhone 11" and other options used to be

Edit: I have updated my project to recommended settings and there was no change.  It is also telling me that there is an error verifying my apple ID but there is nothing for me to verify when I click on the message.

Edit: I clicked the minus button on my Apple ID and xCode immediately quit.  It ran some update and now I "think" its working, except when I tried to log back in it told me that my Apple ID has been locked.